# Android notification displayed at service startup is canceled just after creation

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-notifications

I am testing to make a small application, based on the [Remote Messenger Service Sample](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample)

I have an activity with a button in order to start/stop a service.
After starting the service, I bind the service and the activity, as described in the sample, and everything is working as expected.
The service have a notification, just as the sample: the notification is displayed in the `MessengerService.onCreate()` and canceled in the `MessengerService.onDestroy()`.

Now, I want to start the service automatically when the activity shows up. My activity `onStart()` is as follow (I removed the error checking code to make code more readable):

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    Log.d( TAG, "start service at activity startup" );

    // Start the service automatically
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessengerService.class);
    startService(intent);

    // Bind to the service
    doBindService();
}
```

With doBingService() taken from the sample:

```
void doBindService()
{
    Log.d( TAG, "doBindService call" );

    // Establish a connection with the service.  We use an explicit
    // class name because there is no reason to be able to let other
    // applications replace our component.
    bindService(new Intent(this, MessengerService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}
```

Now, when I start the application from Android Studio to test it, the activity shows up, I can see the notification briefly, and then, the notification disapears after about a second.
The service is still alive, because I can send messages to force the notification to go back.

After some investigations, I saw in the event logs:

```
02-20 22:35:03.342   383   396 I notification_cancel_all: [com.example.messengerservice,-1,0,0]
02-20 22:35:03.545   383   396 I notification_cancel_all: [com.example.messengerservice,-1,0,0]
```

And the corresponding system logs:

```
02-20 22:35:01.154 22884 22884 D example.Activity: start service at activity startup
02-20 22:35:01.170 22884 22884 D example.Activity: doBindService call
02-20 22:35:01.170   383  3814 I ActivityManager: Start proc com.example.messengerservice:notification for service com.example.messengerservice/.MessengerService: pid=22938 uid=10105 gids={50105, 1028}
02-20 22:35:01.232 22938 22938 I example.MessengerService: Service created
02-20 22:35:01.232 22938 22938 D example.MessengerService: Service bound
02-20 22:35:01.232 22938 22938 D example.MessengerService: Service start command
02-20 22:35:01.240 22938 22938 V example.MessengerService: Show notification
[...]
02-20 22:35:03.232   383  3801 I ActivityManager: Start proc com.google.android.apps.plus for broadcast com.google.android.apps.plus/.service.PackagesMediaMonitor: pid=23005 uid=10044 gids={50044, 3003, 3002, 1015, 1006, 1028}
02-20 22:35:03.271 22955 22957 D dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 5% free 9179K/9656K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 28ms
02-20 22:35:03.271 22955 22955 D dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
02-20 22:35:03.357   383   396 D BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.messengerservice flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }
02-20 22:35:03.537 22837 22859 W GAV2    : Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
02-20 22:35:03.537   383   394 W ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) } U=0: not found
02-20 22:35:03.545   383   396 D BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.messengerservice flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }
02-20 22:35:03.545   383   396 V BackupManagerService: removePackageParticipantsLocked: uid=10105 #1
02-20 22:35:03.545   383   396 V BackupManagerService: addPackageParticipantsLocked: #1
```

It seems that when starting the app from Android Studio, I have the following things happening:

- the package is changed
- activity starts (and shows up)
- service is started
- notification is visible
- the system receives PACKAGE_REMOVED/PACKAGE_ADDED and removes all notifications of this package
- the notification is dismissed

My question: How can I keep my notification without being canceled by the system?

Some additional notes:

- Sometimes (about 10% of the times), the notification is not canceled and everything works as expected. But most of the time, the behavior is broken.
- When I start the application from the launcher once installed, and not from Android Studio, everything is fine.
- In these logs, the service is started in another process (android:process=":notification" in the manifest), but starting in the same process does not change the behavior.
- These tests are done on a Galaxy Nexus device, with Android 4.3

**Edit:**

In this example, I understand that in a "real" application, users will propably not open the activity just after upgrading the application, and before the system correctly shut down previous package. I moved the startService out of the activity, in a `PACKAGE_REPLACED` receiver (and handling all the stuff to start the service only if it was running before the new version), but this `PACKAGE_REPLACED` intent is received about 20 seconds after my notification has been canceled. So I still have some time where my service is doing something (for example playing music) with the suitable notification poping out and in 20 seconds later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing a race condition in that you immediately bind the service and show a notification from it. This probably is not noticed much since usually apps don't display a notification immediately in activity onCreate of their main activity.

Try replacing your doBindService with

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doBindService();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Or, just don't worry about it if you are just tesing.

Comment: The notification is started from the onCreate() method of the service, not onBind() So I also put the startService() inside your run(). It is better, but there is still issues where Android kills my notifications more than 1 second after activity startup. Of course I can increase the delay, but it does not look as a "clean" solution working all the time.

Comment: I edited the question, trying to explain why in this very example I can live with it, but in a "real world" application (a music player for example), I am not happy with this behaviour. I can't think of a way to always have a notification up with my service.

Comment: Why would a media player immediately show a notification when the activity is created? Typically if the user is viewing your app they dont need a notification from it also. Notifications are usually shown when your app is in the background.

Comment: After a lot of testing, I accept the "just don't worry about it" part. And in debug mode, I just set a delay of 3 seconds. In release builds, I use the PACKAGE_REPLACED intent to restart the service. It happens only 20-30 seconds after upgrade, but seems less "buggy" to the user than restarting the service at activity startup and the notification disapear because it is too soon after upgrade.
FYI the notification is also shown when the activity is in the foreground, like a "persistant info notification", same as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zzs.notisysinfo

Comment: ok fair enough. I am surprised, 20-30 seconds seems much longer than I expected